# Найти лучший объект в множестве

Tags: c++, поиск, best-practice, контакты

Кто на этом форуме лучше всех знает C++? Напишите свои контакты, есть пару вопросов.

Понятно, тут лучших нет, пойду искать на других форумах.

Comment: @EOF мне не нужны все, только лучшие

Comment: @EOF бред полный

Comment: Лучшие вряд ли будут на вас свое время бесплатно тратить. В любом случае, этот "форум" работает иначе. Вы задаете конкретный вопрос и получаете на него ответ, если этот вопрос хороший.

Comment: @arrowd так кто сказал что бесплатно? Пишите контакты - договоримся

Comment: Думаю, вам нужны фрилансерские сайты, а не Stack Overflow.

Comment: @arrowd мне нужны лучшие, а не студенты

Comment: Что лучших нет? Одни школьники и студенты?

Comment: Ну если вам нужны "Лучшие" обратитесь в крутую аутсорс компанию. Или найдите фрилансера но "Лучшего" у коготорого отменная репутация

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даю контакты лучших:

Howard Hinnant, автор реализации стандартной библиотеки С++:

https://howardhinnant.github.io/HowardHinnant.html

Douglas Gregor, один разработчиков компилятора C++ Clang :

https://www.linkedin.com/in/douggregor

Авторы библиотек из Boost, думаю, весьма шарят:
https://www.boost.org/users/people.html

Comment: Разве они на этом форуме сидят?

Comment: А где Бьёрн Страуструп?

Comment: @EOF решил защитить его от общения с товарищем.

Comment: @Kant Лучшие по тегу С++ на этом форуме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/topusers

Comment: @arrowd больше репутации не означает что они лучшие =/

Comment: А как вы собрались проверять что человек - лучший?

Comment: @arrowd задам некоторые вопросы и посмотрю на ответы

Comment: Ну вот идите по списку и задавайте.

Comment: @arrowd ТАК ГДЕ МНЕ ИХ КОНТАКТЫ ВЗЯТЬ

Comment: Забавно. Если вы в состоянии судить по вопросам-ответам о том, кто лучший, то вы должны справиться со своими проблемами и сами :)